# Is the class of countable posets well-quasi-ordered by embeddability?

Tags: set-theory, order-theory

The question is in the title.  Here "$P$ embeds into $Q$" means there is a function $f : P\to Q$ such that for all $p,p'\in P$, $p \le_P p'$ if and only if $f(p) \le_Q f(p')$.  A *well quasi order* $W$ is a relation which is reflexive and transitive, such that for any infinite sequence $w_1,w_2,\ldots,w_n,\ldots$ taken from the universe of $W$, there are some $n < m$ such that $w_n \le_W w_m$.

My question is motivated by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/459258/the-preorder-of-countable-order-types) other recent question.  [Laver](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1970754) proved that the countable *linear* orders form a wqo under embeddability.  If this holds more generally for countable *partial* orders, then that would imply that the $\bar{\mathcal{O}}$ from the question above has no infinite descending chain or infinite antichain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class of countable partial orders quasi-ordered by embeddability is not well quasi-ordered. Here is a simple example of an infinite antichain taken from M. Pouzet, [Applications of well quasi-ordering and better quasi-ordering](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-94-009-5315-4_15), in Graphs and order (1985), the "*crowns*":
[image]

As far as I know, in the literature, the largest class of countable partial orders known to be wqo (in fact, bqo, of course) under embeddability is the class of $N$-free partial orders, *i.e.* those partial orders in which

[image]

does not embed. This was proved by S. Thomassé in [On better-quasi-ordering countable series-parallel orders](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/stephan.thomasse/liste/better.pdf), Trans. Amer. Math. Soc., 352 (2000), 2491--2505.

Comment: Great answer, thanks!